# Unable to configure Microsoft Identity Platform while publishing .Net Core 3.1.4 project + VS 2022 + Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2022

I have a .net core 3.1 project. The project has a dependency on Microsoft Identity Platform and SQL Server.

While publishing the project to Azure. I am not able to configure the Microsoft Identity Platform. It gives below Error window.

[image]

I am able to configure SQL Server dependency but not sure why it is not able to configure Identity Platform.

I am using

- .Net core 3.1.4
- Visual Studio Community Edition 2022
- Asp.net core Identity Entity Framework 3.1.4

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't install the dotnet-msidentity tool.

You can try to open the `cmd` black window and execute this command following [this document](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/blob/main/src/MSIdentityScaffolding/README.md#installinguninstalling-the-tool).

```
dotnet tool install Microsoft.dotnet-msidentity -g --version "1.0.0-preview.1.21212.1"
```

This command will solve your issue. But then you will meet another issue like screenshot below if your account has multiple tenant.

[image]

Someone met this issue too and raised [a ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Configure-Microsoft-Identity-Platform--/1580609?q=%5BVisual%20Studio%202022%20version%2017.0%5DMicrosoft%20identity%20platform&ftype=problem&space=8&sort=relevance) to ms.

You may search for [known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#-known-issues) here if you meet some other weird questions when using vs2022.

Answer (score 2):

dotnet tool uninstall --global Microsoft.dotnet-msidentity

dotnet tool install Microsoft.dotnet-msidentity -g --version "1.0.2"

worked for me

if you have nuget problems make sure you habe a nuget.config in the directory you are running the command

Answer (score 1):

Make sure nuGet is set as the first or default package source in Visual Studios.
Right click on the project, click on manage nuGet packages and click on the gear next to Package Source.

Verify that nuget.org is setup as the first package source.

Answer (score 1):

I was using my office network, and VS should be opened with Admin mode for
Microsoft.dotnet-msidentity nuget pkg to install.